# Can I get string position in other column

Tags: mysql

If I have two columns and data like:

**column a** | **column b**

```
   1    | 1,2,3,4,5
   4    | 1,2,3,4,5
   5    | 1,2,3,4,5
```

Is there any function to get the `column a` position in `column b`, the first data result is 0, the second is 3, and the third should be 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT col_a, colb_b,
       FIND_IN_SET(col_a, col_b) - 1 AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a3760/3/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╦════════╗
║ cola  ║   colb     ║ result ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬════════╣
║    1  ║ 1,2,3,4,5  ║      0 ║
║    4  ║ 1,2,3,4,5  ║      3 ║
║    5  ║ 1,2,3,4,5  ║      4 ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

If not found you will get `-1`.

In SQL functions are mostly 1-based. That's why you need `-1`.

---

I strongly suggest to normalize your data, and store atomic values in column.

Comment: I know, but it's a special spec for table, really don't want to create a column for it, although it's good for performance, thanks a lot